# CSS: image hovering -> fading away

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover

I'm trying to make an image fade when hovering and just normal when not hovering. When I just put my code in a small html file everything seems to work fine. But when I insert my code into a wordpress website, using the Black Studio Tiny MCE plugin, only the fading away seems to work. Does someone maybe have an idea how to solve this?
Thanks,

J.

```css
#test_menu {
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#test_menu:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;width:496.5px;height:124.125px;">
<a href="https://epowerhr.be/hr-software-oplossing-talent/ehrm-performance-management-software/">
  <img id="test_menu" src="https://epowerhr.be/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/shutterstock_190964189.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;" />
  <p style="z-index:100;position:absolute;color:black;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;left:50px;top:50px;">
    Performance management
  </p></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
img, img:hover {-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; transition: all 0.5s ease;}
img:hover {opacity: 0;}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
```